# Are there any good tools for monitoring EJB container?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, monitoring

I'd like to know how many instances of a certain EJB bean are created. And also their current state, (i.e. which one is passivated or activated). So far, the only way I use to monitor beans life cycle is the debugging mode (like constructor calls, @PostContruct methods...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question may depend on which application server you are running, but if the server you are running is fully Java EE compatible, they should provide some EJB statistics according to [JSR 77](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=77) as managed objects via JMX. I'd suggest reviewing your application server's documentation further as well.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the corresponding JSR! Actually, I asked in general, for any Java EE compliant app server.

Comment: Since there are no other answers, I'm gonna mark this one as accepted. However, I'll be glad to hear another responses as well. If I come up with any solution myself, I'm gonna post it here.

Comment: we are using jboss-eap, is there any good tool for monitoring session beans?